# Cast an instance of a class to a @protocol in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I have an object (a UIViewController) which may or may not conform to a protocol I've defined.

I know I can determine if the object conforms to the protocol, then safely call the method:

```
if([self.myViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)]) {
    [self.myViewController protocolMethod]; // <-- warning here
}
```

However, XCode shows a warning:

```
warning 'UIViewController' may not respond to '-protocolMethod'
```

What's the right way to prevent this warning?  I can't seem to cast `self.myViewController` as a `MyProtocol` class.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to do:

```
if ([self.myViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)])
{
        UIViewController <MyProtocol> *vc = (UIViewController <MyProtocol> *) self.myViewController;
        [vc protocolMethod];
}
```

The `UIViewController <MyProtocol> *` type-cast translates to "vc is a UIViewController object that conforms to MyProtocol", whereas using `id <MyProtocol>` translates to "vc is an object of an unknown class that conforms to MyProtocol".

This way the compiler will give you proper type checking on `vc` - the compiler will only give you a warning if any method that's not declared on either `UIViewController` or `<MyProtocol>` is called. `id` should only be used in the situation if you don't know the class/type of the object being cast.

Comment: When using protocols you really shouldn't care about the object type -- the whole point of a protocol is that any object type can adopt it and be used without having to cast to the specific object. So, I would recommend using the answer by @andy anywhere you are casting to a protocol instead of the above -- `id<MyProtocol> p = (id<MyProtocol>)self.myViewController;` This answer and @andys are both correct, but his is _more_ correct.

Comment: @Answerbot your comment is incorrect, and misses the point I made in the last paragraph of my answer. You might or might not care about the object type, it depends on the situation. What happens if you want to send a message declared on `UIViewController` to `vc` in the example in my answer, and it's declared as `id <MyProtocol>`?

Comment: Not sure what in regards to my comment is incorrect? In any case, if you are checking if an object conforms to a protocol why would you then call some other method unrelated to the protocol? I can't recall ever needing to do this or seeing this in code I've reviewed. Seems like a code smell to me.

Comment: Just because you haven't seen/used it, doesn't mean it's a code smell. Here's a code snippet showing one example of where throwing away type information by using `id` is a problem: https://gist.github.com/nsforge/7743616

Answer (score 65):

You can cast it like this:

```
if([self.myViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)])
{
    id<MyProtocol> p = (id<MyProtocol>)self.myViewController;
    [p protocolMethod];
}
```

This threw me for a bit, too. In Objective-C, the protocol isn't the type itself, so you need to specify `id` (or some other type, such as `NSObject`) along with the protocol that you want.

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks.  I just checked and saw that casting it as `(id)` works too.  Is that bad form?

Comment: If you cast it as id<MyProtocol> then the compiler will warn you if you use methods that aren't defined in that protocol.

Comment: @dreamlax - This is how the compiler does type checking against protocols. See http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/chapter_7_section_11.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF151 for more info.

Comment: @Ford - it would be better to use the the protocol specifically, since that way the compiler can perform some type checking for you.

Comment: @Andy, I don't think you need the '*' since 'id' is already a pointer.  So:

    id<MyProtocol> p = (id<MyProtocol>)self.myViewController;
    [p protocolMethod];

Or just:

    [(id<MyProtocol>)self.myViewController protocolMethod];

Comment: anyone knows why this puts in me in an infinite loop when called on a subclass of `UICollectionView` with `if([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)])`?