# Why can't a variable typed as id<someProtocol> receive a parameter of id<otherProtocol> even if 'otherProtocol' conforms to 'someProtocol'?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, polymorphism, protocols

Imagine I have two protocols:

```
@protocol A
@end
```

and

```
@protocol B <A> // Protocol B conforms to protocol A.
@end
```

And also two variables:

```
id<A> myVar = nil;
```

and

```
id<B> otherVar = //correctly initialized to some class that conforms to <B>;
```

Then, why can't I assign 'otherVar' to 'myVar'?

```
myVar = otherVar; //Warning, sending id<B> to parameter of incompatible type id<A>
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try casting the variable?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are the protocols in separate files? What headers are you importing and where?

Comment: Yes, the protocols are in separate files. The problem was with the visibility of the files. I was using a forward declaration when I should have imported the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the protocol's (`B`) declaration (not just its forward declaration) visible? And does the declaration precede `myVar = otherVar;`?

When the declaration order is correct, clang did not complain.

To illustrate:

```
@protocol A
@end

@protocol B; // << forward B

void fn() {
    id<A> myVar = nil;
    id<B> otherVar = nil;
    myVar = otherVar; // << warning
}

// declaration follows use, or is not visible:    
@protocol B <A>
@end
```

whereas the properly ordered version produces no warning:

```
@protocol A
@end

@protocol B <A>
@end

void fn() {
    id<A> myVar = nil;
    id<B> otherVar = nil;
    myVar = otherVar;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! You were right, the problem was in the visibility of the protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it `conformsToProtocol()` and if so then cast it like so

```
myVar = (id <A>)otherVar;
```

A similar question can be viewed at [Cast an instance of a class to a @protocol in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617616/cast-an-instance-of-a-class-to-a-protocol-in-objective-c)