# Cast UIView nextResponder to UITableView delegate

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, casting, delegates

Within a UIView how do I cast self.nextResponder (which points to the view's controller) to avoid a compiler warning on the third line below?

```
UITableView* tableView = [ [ UITableView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.tag = TAG_IMAGEADMIN_IMAGESLISTVIEW;
tableView.delegate = self.nextResponder; // compiler warning here
tableView.dataSource = self;
[self addSubview:tableView];
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast an instance of a class to a @protocol in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617616/cast-an-instance-of-a-class-to-a-protocol-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast to a protocol as follows:

```
tableView.delegate = (id<UITableViewDelegate>)self.nextResponder
```

Answer (score 0):

As UITableViewDelegate is a protocol, you can cast as

tableView.delegate = (id < UITableViewDelegate >)self.nextResponder.
This tells the compiler that self.nextResponder is any object that confirms to UITableViewDelegate protocol.

If you know that the nextResponder is of any perticular  class lets say UIViewController, you can write as

tableView.delegate = (UIViewController < UITableViewDelegate>*)self.nextResponder.
This tells compiler that nextResponder is of type UIViewController class that confirms to UITableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: Complete discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617616/cast-an-instance-of-a-class-to-a-protocol-in-objective-c