# How to define a `Class` object type conforming to a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, introspection, static-typing, objective-c-protocol

Consider the following Objective-C protocol declaration, which requires only class methods:

```objc
@protocol TDWMethoding<NSObject>

+ (void)foo;
+ (void)bar;

@end
```

Assuming I need to return an instance of a `Class` which conforms to this protocol from a method, how am I supposed to specify the return type?

```objc
- (nullable /*return-type*/)instantiateMethoding {
    Class instance = ... // some implementation
    if ([instance conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TDWMethoding)]) {
        return instance;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

There are a number of *working* options I considered so far in regards to how to express the `/*return-type*/`, but each has its own downsides:

1. `Class` - this way it doesn't expose conformance. What kind of `Class` is it? What does it do? Does it conform to the protocol at all?
2. `Class<TDWMethoding>` - this looks like a viable solution and even was suggested a few times by other developers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10075402/5690248) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078012/how-to-cast-class-object-to-conformance-witih-protocol#comment19468613_14079532)) but I personally find it inconsistent and misleading: when we have a variable of form `Type<Protocol> *instance`, it commonly means that protocol class methods should be sent to the instance's class (`[[instance class] foo]`) not the instance itself (`[instance foo]`);
3. `id<TDWMethoding>` and returning an instance of the class instead - this is consistent, but it requires me to instantiate the class, which is both redundant and prevents me from hiding the constructors of the utility classes which conforms to the protocol with `NS_UNAVAILABLE` macro.

Is there a better semantic to express such a return-type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a little deeper into [The Objective-C Programming Language documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF151), I actually found the exact answer to such a scenario:

> Protocols can’t be used to type class objects. Only instances can be statically typed to a protocol, just as only instances can be statically typed to a class. (However, at runtime, both classes and instances respond to a `conformsToProtocol:` message.)

Which means that it's just not supported and I should implement this differently. (e.g. with use of a singleton pattern, as suggested in [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75162261/5690248))

Answer (score 0):

`Class<TDWMethoding>` is correct. It's not inconsistent. When something is of type `Class`, you send class methods to it. When something is an instance, and you want to send to the class, you access its `-class`.

That said, this does seem very strange, and likely means you're overusing Class methods. You should think hard about whether a `sharedInstance` is a better model for this.

But if you want to identify the type, `Class<TDWMethoding>` is correct, though `id` would likely be more common, as discussed in [How to cast Class object to conformance witih protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078012/how-to-cast-class-object-to-conformance-witih-protocol#comment19468613_14079532).

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but how do you know that `Class<TDWMethoding>` and `id<TDWMethoding>` should have different contract? Also, provided `Class`/`objc_class` is itself an `objc_type` you can impose protocol conformance on the metaclass of the class, which makes it possible to send class methods messages to the metaclass object of the `Class<TDWMethoding>` instance

Answer (score 0):

The solution is doesn't use such protocols at all. Why? Because it's inflexible.

It should be just:

```
@protocol TDWMethoding

- (void)foo;
- (void)bar;

@end
```

Then you will be able to do any what you want, for example you will be able to create wrapper for yours class, that will be implementing yours protocol.

```
@interface TDWMethodingModel<TDWMethoding>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) void (^fooCaller)(void);
@property (nonatomic, readonly) void (^barCaller)(void);

- (instancetype)initWithFooCaller:(void (^)(void))fooCaller barCaller:(void (^)(void))barCaller NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

@end

@implementation TDWMethodingModel

- (instancetype)initWithFooCaller:(void (^)(void))fooCaller barCaller:(void (^)(void))barCaller {
  self = [super init];
  if (nil == self) {
    return nil;
  }
  _fooCaller = fooCaller;
  _barCaller = barCaller;
  return self;
}

- (void)foo {
  self.fooCaller();
}

- (void)bar {
  self.barCaller();
}

@end
```

then:

```
- (id<TDWMethoding>)instantiateMethoding
{
  static id<TDWMethoding> methoding;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    methoding = [[TDWMethodingModel alloc] initWithFooCaller:^{
      [SomeClass foo];
    } barCaller:^{
      [SomeClass bar];
    }];
  });
  return methoding;
}
```

Comment: P.S. I have removed `<NSObject>` because we doesn't have optional methods here and it will be better for compatibility with swift